# How to access value of variable inside "for_ in range(5)"

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop

I done a for loop like:

```
for _ in range(5):
     name = input()
     score = float(input())
```

now I want to access value of name at position 1.

So how I can do this?

I try `print(name[0])`, but it shows like `TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable`

Comment: rather than two lists, I recommend you define a dictionary prior to your for loop and after setting those variables inside the loop, use then as the key and value to update your dictionary

Answer (score 0):

The values you get inside your loop need to be stored somewhere. A list is a good choice of where to store such values. Try this:

```
names = []
scores = []
for _ in range(5):
    name = input()
    score = float(input())

    names.append(name)
    scores.append(score)

print(names[0])
```